# Track Window "Close" (X) on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Is it possible to track the window closing event on iPad ? This is when a user closes a window from the minimized/grid view on the iPad.
In other words, I want to track the equivalent of onbeforeunload or onunload events which are used to track window closing on Desktop browsers?

window.onbeforeunload is not working on the iPad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try to add onUnload property to

Comment: For reference, you can edit your answer to fix missing text. You'll see the `edit` link underneath the answer itself, on the left.